Allow grid row to increase in height from one column but not other
My objective is to make images have the same height of description. Currently, images can be much larger if the image src is very tall vertically:


article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title title" "images description";
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  padding: 8px;
}

.images {
  grid-area: images;
}

img {
  display: block;
  /* max-width: 100%; */
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
  padding: 8px;
}
<article>
  <div class="title">There are many other articles like this one on the page</div>
  <div class="images">
    <img alt="random image" src="https://i.sstatic.net/MB9ui48p.png">
    <img alt="random image" src="https://i.sstatic.net/MB9ui48p.png">
  </div>
  <div class="description">The description of the thing. The description of the thing. The description of the thing. The description of the thing. The description of the thing. The description of the thing.</div>
</article>



Setting the CSS for img {max-width: 100%;} gets me exactly what I want, as long as the image is not too big vertically. If the image is vertically big, then the .images div gets expanded too much, to cover all of the 100% width image, and then it dwarfs the .description div to the right of it.
Most answers I saw here in SO mention setting max-height: 100%, but it makes no difference in my case. Others suggested putting img as background to a div, but this seems like a hack.
I tried making the .images container a flexbox, but also made no difference in constraining the vertical size.
What worked best so far was setting img {max-height: 50vh}, but it's not exactly the same as making .images have the same height of .description.

Does the parent container (e.g., article or its parent) have a defined height? If it doesn’t, you might not see the intended behaviour. And does articles have it's grid columns and rows set up with a height as well? I understand that the text may be different sizes, but if you can control these elements you have images and description the same size with: .images, .description {
height: 100%;
}

@MarcInglis Well spotted! No, parent nor container have a set height. The issue is that description can vary in length/height, so I don't know what I could put there. I tried to change them now to {height: 100%}, but it made no difference

I just thought now I could do, instead of a grid, a <div display:flex>images description</div>, but I'd run into the same problem where it might not be possible to force images to have the height of description in that flexbox

Hmmm but i think you're right, I need to do a <div>images description</div> and set that wrapper div to a given height. Still, it might simply not be possible to make the .description be able to grow as much as it want, but not the .images?

Do you want the images folder to be just as wide as the image, or 50% width of the layout?

@ralph.m the width is working well, and yes, I wanted it to be ~50% of the layout (for some reason it's never exactly 50% with this grid layout, but close enough for my purposes)

So if there's not much description text, there might be a lot of while space between it and the image?

@ralph.m sorry, you're right! it'll vary... I can't have both 50% width and height. But what is really important for me is the height only, it's ok if the width varies a lot as long as the image isn't strecthed

One way you can do it is like this, although with a small amount of description you'll get a lot of space between image and text.


article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title title" "images description";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

.images {
  grid-area: images;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f49c9c;
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.images>img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: 0 0;
}
<article>
  <div class="title">There are many other articles like this one on the page</div>
  <div class="images">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="description">The description of the thing</div>
</article>



You could let the description take up more of that space if you like, or set the image to cover the whole space, but that often wouldn't look very nice.
Edit: one limitation here is that you can only have one image in there. I've put in two, but they sit on top of each other. If you want multiple images in there, then this won't work!

Description seems to cut off at tall sizes

I sometimes have 2 imgs...! It can be either 1 or 2 imgs. But this is a very smart solution for 1 img, I tried it on my page and it worked great, except for the width of some images which overflew with position:absolute, but this could probably be tweaked too

Ah, good points about the long text. I've updated it to deal with the longer text. One hack for the two images would be to put the two images into one image …

Ouch, that was painful, but I figured out a couple of other ways to do 2 imgs with this code. The easiest one is to add CSS rules: img {height: 50%;}   img:nth-child(2) {top: 50%;}

Here's a grid solution that uses container queries which allow the grid to ignore how large the images want to be:


article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title title" "images description";
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  grid-area: title;
  padding: 8px;
}

.images {
  grid-area: images;
  container-type: size;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100cqw - 15px);
}

.description {
  grid-area: description;
  padding: 8px;
}
<article>
  <div class="title">There are many other articles like this one on the page</div>
  <div class="images">
    <img alt="random image" src="https://i.sstatic.net/MB9ui48p.png">
    <img alt="random image" src="https://i.sstatic.net/MB9ui48p.png">
  </div>
  <div class="description">The description of the thing. The description of the thing. The description of the thing. The description of the thing. The description of the thing. The description of the thing.</div>
</article>



width: calc(100cqw - 15px); on your images sizes them to be as wide as their container minus the width of any scrollbar (you might need to adjust the 15px if it overflows in your testing)

This solution is perfect!! It's exactly what I wanted, with only 1 thing missing: would it be possible to make img resize to fit container instead of having a scroll overflow?

@flen Yes. Your options are the following: Images scroll, Images stretch, Images tiny

Thanks! How does one do the image tiny? I'm sorry, I think I've been a bit confusing, but instead of having the width fit perfectly the 50% of the page, I'd prefer to have the width vary, but resizing the image (and keeping it in scale, instead of stretching it) so the height would be limited to the description height (i.e., the image would be tiny)

Looks like Ralph has already solved that for you

That's true, though only for 1 image (or 2 if they get pasted together elsewhere and then added as 1 img)
